# What does $\frac{\textrm{$d^2$}y}{\textrm{d}x^2}=0$ at any arbitrary point $x=c$ represents in general?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This question was asked by my University professor.Many students answered it as the rate of change of  first derivative,but this seems to me a crammed notion,also professor was not satisfied by this answer.Some answered it a line.But, second derivative of $x^4$ at $x=0$ is also zero but this not a line.
Hence, I wanted to know the answer to this problem.

Any hints are heartly welcome.

Thank You

Comment: Note that : At any point ...suppose a function that has no inflection point .hope that it make a sense

Comment: Integrate this *twice* at *any* closed interval to show that it's a *straight line*.

Comment: @M.Boyet:Second derivative of $y=x^4-x$ at $x=0 $ is also zero but zero is not the inflexion point for $y$

Comment: Do you mean that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$ _everywhere_, or just that there is _some particular_ $x$ where this is true? The first of these is true only for straight lines; the second is true for $x^4$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm:Here,$x=c$ is any arbitrary real number.

Comment: @PKStyles: That does not answer my question. Are you saying that $\frac{d^y}{dx^2}$ is true for _every_ arbitrary $x=c$ or just for one particular $c$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm:Sorry my bad,i did'nt get your question.I'm saying that it is true for every $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f''(x)=0$ is true for *every* $x$, then we must have $f'(a)=f'(b)$ for every $a$ and $b$ (use the mean value theorem on $f'$).

So there is an $m$ such that $f'(x)=m$ for every $x$.

Using the mean value theorem once again now tells us
$$ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = m \qquad\text{which gives}\qquad
f(x) = mx+f(0) $$
so $f$ must be a linear function.

On the other hand, every linear function satisfies $f''(x)=0$ everywhere, as we can see by differentiating $f(x)=mx+b$ symbolically twice.

---

$f(x)=x^4$ is not a counterexample to this: We do have $f''(0)=0$, but $f''(1)=4$, so this function does not satisfy $f''(x)=0$ for *every* $x$.

Comment: Markholm:thanks a lot  sir.I  come to know about a new approach by this.

Comment: :Sir,how will the answer gets changed if talk about particular point $x=c$?

Comment: Protip: Don't "sir" random people on the internet who just wanted to help. I am neither a customer in your business nor your military superior!

Comment: :ok, now i'm angry at you(lols).Now,Will you please suggest some solution to my query?

Comment: Not with that kind of attitude I won't. I'm doing this in my free time, for no tangible benefit at all; the least I think I can reasonably expect is not to be insulted by the people I try to help.

Comment: Mokholm:I'm SERIOUSLY angry now.

Comment: Good luck with that, "SIR". You can write the corporate office and get every penny you paid for my attempt to help back.

Comment: :I did'nt have any intention to hurt you.I thought you were kidding.That's why i answered mischieviosly.If you don't want to answer then don't do.But,please don't think bad of me.I explored your profile you're an  intellect guy.I'm a student &I called you "SIR" just to pay respect.And,If you think that i am insulting you then please forgive me.

Comment: :I'm Sorry   [:-(]